# xml 1.0 and 1.1 inside svg file?

Tags: xml, text, svg, adobe-illustrator, xml-1.1

I have a file with xml 1.1 and I need to modify it with adobe illustrator (I need to convert all the tags "text" into curves).

But illustrator doesn't open xml 1.1, it will open it if I'll modify it to xml 1.0. But if I do this then some labels will be converted incorrectly.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by *some labels will be converted incorrectly*? Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

solved. The problem was with coordinates.

Another version of my application for another platform (which is not written by me) shows all the labels correctly but in general it parses them via wrong way. I have found that chrome, inkscape and my version of app show this svg as the same picture.

The problem is with interpreting of rotation angle. So it is better to change the svg file to write the same point for positioning and rotating.